# Google sheet scripts ContactsApp.createContact Invalid request

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a project that adds members to my Contacts from a sheet. It's been running okay for two years.

A few days ago I changed the password for Gmail and afterward I begin receiving the error `ContactsApp: Invalid request`.

I created a file with only this function, and the answer is the same

```
function myFunction() 
{
    var contact = ContactsApp.createContact('John', 'Doe', 'john.doe@example.com');
}
```

I can't locate the problem.

Thank's for the help.

Comment: How does this function add members to Contacts from a sheet?  There must be more to your function. Take a look at [mcve]

Comment: @Cooper Thank's This function is used only for debug. When i use this in another google account, the member is create, not in this account. The exact function was ok during more than 2 years, and suddenly after changing the gmail password this message appears. Merci pour votre aide